# how to call a custom jquery function without attaching it to something

Tags: javascript, jquery

new to writing a function in jquery, just testing the waters.

I have this just to to demo:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.update_notifications = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            user_id: 0,
        }, options );

        alert('test');

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Which I include in a JS file included before the  tag. What I want to know, is how to actually call it inside my html?

I was thinking something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.update_notifications({
    user_id: 1
});
</script>
```

But that tells me "jQuery.update_notifications is not a function"

Comment: Change `$.fn.update_notifications...` to just `$.update_notifications...`. Although that said, your example seems a little redundant. It's just a wrapper for `$.extend()` which add no logic.

Comment: Are you sure? Even their docs https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ say to do this?

Comment: That is to create a plugin to be called on an instance of a jQuery object.

Comment: There's no point in extending the jQuery object if the function doesn't do anything with jQuery objects. Just make a normal function.

Comment: @JJJ it will later be expanded to adjust some on screen elements, which i will be doing with jquery

Comment: Then why do you need to call it without selecting elements? If you just need to test it before it acts on the elements, just call it with any random selector like `$('div').update_notifications()`.

Comment: To put the comments another way - you would only create a `$.fn.plugin = function...` plugin *if* you want it to run on a jquery collection / selector,  eg `$("div").plugin()`.  If you just want to call it as-is `$.fn.plugin()` without any context, then just create a function in your *own* namespace (or global) ie `function plugin() { }`

Comment: Ah, that explains it a little further, I think I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call it on selected element like this:

```
$("some_element").update_notifications();
```

You can find more here at the [official documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#basic-plugin-authoring).

Comment: So there's no way to do it, without attaching it to an element? Like in that example, it's not attached to anything, it's just using an alert.

Comment: If you want to create an independent helper function, there's no need to attach it to jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, the function is not part of the jquery object, but of its *fn* child object

```
$.fn.update_notifications();
```

However, it doesnt make sense to add something to the jquery prototype if youre not doing sth *jqueryobjectbased*

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you simply need to change `$.fn.update_notifications` to `$.update_notifications`. The `$.fn` namespace is used for attaching functions to instances of jQuery objects.

```js
(function($) {
  $.update_notifications = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      user_id: 0,
    }, options);

    console.log('test');
  };
}(jQuery));

jQuery.update_notifications({
  user_id: 1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That being said, your example is a little redundant as you've just wrapped the existing `$.extend()` function without adding any real logic - although I assume this is a work in progress.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thought I'd better mention it, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

If your function has nothing to do with any DOM elements, i would suggest you not to pollute jQuery. You can very well declare this function some where else (page, separate JS file etc.).

But if you still want to do this, you can try these

```
$.update_notifications();
```

or

```
$(window).update_notifications();
```

or

```
$(document).update_notifications();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you exactly extending the Jquery object?

Usually, lacking a valid reason to do so you would simply write a function inside your script.

Let's assume you have a valid reason and proceed:

Once you bind your function to $ or better create object like $.custom and bind the function (and rest of custom things you wanna bind to Jquery) you can use it like a normal function - only prefix it with $.custom

Not sure I understand your question but are you searching how to run that function from HTML other than using jquery?

Are you asking for an example like this?

`<p id="onThis" onclick="$.custom.yourFunctionName()">Click me.</p>`

That is obtrusive JS code and is not best practice when dealing with Jquery.

You wanna bind that function to element with on or click handler when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#onThis').on('click', function here);
 // OR //
 $('#onThis').click(function here);
```

});

If there is no reason to bind it to jQuery, don't do it you are only implying to someone reading your code something that doesn't exist ;)